# aws cli copy command halted

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I used Putty to get into my AWS instance and ran a cp command to copy files into my S3 instance.

```
aws cli cp local s3://server_folder --recursive
```

Partway through, my internet dropped out and the copy halted even though the AWS instances was still running properly. Is there a way to make sure the cp command keeps running even if I lose my connection?

Answer (score 1):

You can alternatively use [Minio Client aka mc](https://minio.io/downloads/),it is open source and is compatible with AWS S3. Minio client is available for Windows along with mac, Linux.

The *mc mirror* command will help you in copying local content to remote AWS S3 bucket, incase of network issue the upload fails *mc session resume* will start uploading from where connection was terminated.

mc supports these commands.

```
COMMANDS:
  ls        List files and folders.
  mb        Make a bucket or folder.
  cat       Display contents of a file.
  pipe      Write contents of stdin to one target. When no target is specified, it writes to stdout.
  share     Generate URL for sharing.
  cp        Copy one or more objects to a target.
  mirror    Mirror folders recursively from a single source to single destination.
  diff      Compute differences between two folders.
  rm        Remove file or bucket [WARNING: Use with care].
  access    Set public access permissions on bucket or prefix.
  session   Manage saved sessions of cp and mirror operations.
  config    Manage configuration file.
  update    Check for a new software update.
  version   Print version.
```

You can check [docs.minio.io](https://docs.minio.io/docs/minio-client-complete-guide) for more details.

Hope it helps.

Disclaimer: I work for Minio.